# Optimal Matching with MatchIt restricted to region of common support

Tags: r, matching

I am using MatchIt to try different matching models and achieve balance between treatment and control group.

One of the models I specify uses optimal matching. However, this method often gives worst results than nearest neighbour matching with caliper. This is because it matches all treatment units to a control unit, whereas nearest neighbour allows for discarding such units with the options "discard" or "caliper".

I know that there is no way to implement the caliper directly on optimal matching with MatchIt. However, is there a way to run optimal matching with the units that fall only within the region of common support?

Answer (score 0):

You can use calipers and common support with optimal matching in `MatchIt`.

For common support, just use the standard common support argument (i.e., `discard`). `matchit()` processes this argument and performs the common support pruning before processing the matching algorithm.

For calipers, you can supply the width of the caliper to the `caliper` argument. Note that by default, this works differently from the `caliper` argument when doing nearest neighbor matching, in that it is not in standard deviation units. To ensure it is in standard deviation units, set `standardization.scale = sd` (yes, no quotes around `sd`). The reason this is so is that `matchit()` passes arguments down to `fullmatch()` in the `optmatch` package, and while `fullmatch()` doesn't have a `caliper` argument, it accepts arguments from `match_on()`, which *does* have a `caliper` argument. I agree that this is quite obscure and it would be nice if the `MatchIt` documentation was clearer on this.

Comment: Thanks Noah. However, it looks as if this is not working. Using a caliper does not change results (even when restricting it to 0.001). Also, discard function gives error: Error in d[i, ] <- abs(d1[i] - d0) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Wow, you're right. The issue with `discard` only seems to be a problem for me when I use the `hull.` methods, but not the others (e.g., `discard = "control"`). There may be some nuance to the use of `caliper` in `match_on()` that I am not understanding, because I can't get them to work reliably there either.